# Carrierwave images are not displaying, works everywhere else on the site

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm using Carrierwave with Rails to upload and display images. I've been using it for articles and other parts of my site without a problem but for some reason it's not working for the model I just created. I can see the space for the image tag rendered without the image and then disappear quickly when the page loads. Nothing like this has occurred until I tried it with this model which isn't much different from my other models:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_numericality_of :zip_code
  validates_presence_of :image, :advertiser

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

My create and index actions:

```
  def create
    @ad = Ad.new(params[:ad].permit(:image, :advertiser, :zip_code))

    if @ad.save
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:error] = "Invalid input"
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  def index
    @new_ad = Ad.new
    @ads = Ad.all.reverse
  end
```

My _new partial:

```
<div id="card">
<%= form_for @new_ad, html: {multipart: true, "data-ajax" => false} do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.text_field :advertiser, placeholder: "Advertiser" %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.text_field :zip_code, placeholder: "Zip code" %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
</div></br>
```

My index view:

```
<%= render "new" %>

<% for ad in @ads %>
    <div id="card">
        <div align="center">
            <%= image_tag ad.image %>
            <%= ad.advertiser %>
            <%= ad.zip_code %>
        </div>
    </div></br>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding problem is with your index view.

```
<%= image_tag ad.image %>
```

you are using ad.image this will return you imageuploader object not image path. So instead of using ad.image you can use ad.image.url(relative path) or ad.image.current_path(absolute path)

```
<%= image_tag ad.image.url %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried image_url and image.url but both generated the same HTML as ad.image and it even matches my other models that are displaying images correctly. Is there anything else that could be wrong?